# Whats the difference between newSlot and setSlot in the Io Language?

Tags: iolanguage

In the Io Language, there are 2 methods for creating slots: newSlot and setSlot. Both seem to have similar behavior except newSlot also creates a setter. What cases are there for a needing a setter to be created at the same time as slot creation? What exactly is the purpose of the setter anyway?

Comment: I was also wondering what a setter was at the end of the first day of Io in 7 languages in 7 weeks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe its a convenience which provides good coding practises.  Thus if you want to expose an objects attribute then `newSlot` or its synonym `::=` are the preferred way to go.

`newSlot` can make things look nicer. For eg.

```
Animal := Object clone do (
    legs ::= nil    // creates leg slot  & setLegs() setter
    tail ::= nil    // creates tail slot & setTail() setter
)

// I think below is more aesthetic 
Cat := Animal clone setLegs(4) setTail(1)

// compared to this
Dog := Animal clone do (legs = 4; tail = 1)
```

And also it can get around `do()` context.  For eg.

```
Pet := Animal clone do (
    name ::= nil
)

myPetCats := list("Ambrose", "Fluffy", "Whiskers") map (petName,
    Pet clone do (name = petName)   // throws exception
)
```

The `Pet clone do (name = petName)` will die throwing `Exception: Pet does not respond to 'petName'` because `do()` is interpreted within the cloned `Pet` context and so it cannot see `petName`.

So instead you need to use the setter:

```
myPetCats := list("Ambrose", "Fluffy", "Whiskers") map (petName,
    Pet clone setName(petName)
)
```